# Get key names in json file in delphi

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-7

I have a json string format like this:

```json
{
  "LIST":{
    "Joseph":{  
      "item1":0,
      "item2":0
    },
    "John":{
      "item1":0,
      "item2":0
    },
    "Fred":{
      "item1":0,
      "item2":0
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the names, "Joseph", "John", "Fred" and so on... I have a function that will add names to the list, I have no idea what names will be added so I need to get those names.

I can only get the name "LIST" with this code:

```
js := TlkJSONstreamed.loadfromfile(jsonFile) as TlkJsonObject;
try
 ShowMessage( vartostr(js.NameOf[0]) );
finally
 s.free;
end;
```

I'm using lkJSON-1.07 in delphi 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the names in turn and obtain the next object for each name.

1. Get the name: `js.NameOf[0]`
2. Obtain the object from the name: `js[js.NameOf[0]]`

---

The `getJSONNames` procedure prints all the names contained in a `TlkJSONobject` object recursively.

```
procedure getJSONNames(const Ajs: TlkJSONobject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Ajs = nil then
    Exit
  else
    for i := 0 to Ajs.Count-1 do begin
      WriteLn(Ajs.NameOf[i]);
      getJSONNames(TlkJSONobject(Ajs[Ajs.NameOf[i]]));
    end;
end;

var
  js: TlkJsonObject;
begin
  js := TlkJSONstreamed.loadfromfile(jsonFile) as TlkJsonObject;
  try
    getJSONNames(js);
  finally
    js.free;
  end;
end.
```